# Trying to show error messages, but running into: undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

I am trying to implement error messages in Rails and I somehow fail to get it to work at one point.

The View I am trying to add the error messages:

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build], html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>

            <% if @comment.errors.any? %>

                <div id="errorExplanation" class="span5 offset1 alert alert-error">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>

                    <h4>Something went wrong!</h4><br>

                    <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <p><%= msg %></p>
                    <% end %>
                </div>

        <% end %>
```

And the controller:

```
def create
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:commenter, :body))
redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
```

And the error message:

undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #65):

```
<li>
            <%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build], html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>

65 ->                       <% if @comment.errors.any? %>

                    <div id="errorExplanation" class="span5 offset1 alert alert-error">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
```

The Comments of course belong to a post which can have many comments. Any help? I tried everything I could think of (which is not much since I am new to RoR ;) - including various ways of trying to get the error messages (@post.comment.errors.any? etc.).

Thanks in advance.
Timo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments there are many things going on here.

You're trying to create a comment, so the form action should be CommentsController#create.
The view makes sense that it would be PostsController#show (you don't specify), and before rendering you need to instantiate @comment. Possibly:

**PostsController**

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @comment = @post.comments.build
end
```

**CommentsController**

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment].permit(:commenter, :body))
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  else
    render :file => "posts/show"
  end 
end
```

Note that you must render and not redirect so you keep a hold of the @comment instance and can render errors.

**posts/show.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build], html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
    <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
```

Whether this is correct will depend on your routes.rb. I'm assuming comments is a nested resource in posts, which is what your question leads to think.

Comment: Hey boulder - thanks for the answer, but the error is earlier in line 65 (please see the edited question). Apparently @comment.errors.any? is wrong, but I cant figure out why.

Comment: I suspect that you're getting the error on 'new', not 'create'. What does your `def new` action look like? Are you instantiating @comment there as well? Something like `@comment =  @post.comments.build`

Comment: Also, which controller are you showing, PostsController or CommentsController?

Comment: it used to look like: def new '@comment = Comment.new' i tried '@comment = @post.comments.build' still nothing. Sorry

Comment: Full rewrite of my answer. Hopefully this helps you.